# JSON SerDe for Hive that supports JSON arrays

Tags: json, serialization, hive

I have tried the JSON SerDe that Amazon provides for EMR instance and works great if you need to address/map JSON dictionary fields to columns. However I wasn't been able to figure how to do the same with JSON arrays. For example if there is a JSON array as follows:

> [23123.32, "Text Text", { "key1": "value1" } ]

Is there a way to map the first element of an array to a column in Hive table? What about the embedded dictionary fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem till I found this serde on github -
https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde
Just include it using the 'add jar' command once you start hive and it works like a charm.

Comment: Hi @pmohan6, Do you know how to run it for HDP 2.5.6?