# How to read arrays from a JSON document in EMR hive?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

Does Amazon hive jsonserde.jar support arrays? If so, could you please show me a simple example how to read Json arrays with Amazon jsonserde.jar. I want to now how to set the path propertie of SerDe when I define an array column in a table.

Comment: maybe replicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966349/json-serde-for-hive-that-supports-json-arrays

Answer (score 0):

I think you 'll be able to find a solution by referring this example.
here is the link....

https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: thanks, but my question is specifically is about the SerDe provided by Amazon . s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar;